# Value of $T_q(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{q}}\sum_{c=0}^{q-1}w^{\frac{c(c-1)}{2}\cdot k}$ where $w=e^{2\pi i/q}$, with $q$ prime

Tags: number-theory

What is the value of
$$T_q(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{q}}\sum_{c=0}^{q-1}w^{\frac{c(c-1)}{2}\cdot k}$$
where $w=e^{2\pi i/q}$, with $q$ prime? (and $k\neq0$)

---

I was just able to compute the square of this quantity, I get
$$T_q(k)^2=(-1)^{\frac{q-1}{2}}w^{\frac{q^2-1}{4}\cdot k}$$
and the problem is that of extracting the square root. At $k=1$ the square root is
$$T_q(1)=(-i)^{\frac{q-1}{2}}w^{\frac{q^2-1}{8}}$$ 
but at $k>1$ the problem looks much harder. I think that we should have
$$T_q(k)=i^{\varphi_q(k)}w^{\frac{q^2-1}{8}\cdot k}$$
for some tricky exponent $\varphi_q(k)$, that I'm not able at all to calculate.

Any help welcome!

Comment: See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum

Comment: Wow, thanks! Problem solved. Btw what a genius this Gauss guy (I've been struggling with this for a few days, without much clues :) Thanks again.